# "Error while processing typedef" when #include on C in VScode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

I'm using VScode to learn C and everytime I put the #include sentence, this error appears

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("testing");
}

Error while processing C/C++(clang-diagnostic-error) Ln1, Col 1
stddef.hLn 216, Col 23: typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned int' vs 'unsigned long long')
```

Looks like something goes wrong in MinGW libs, but as a fresh on the programming world, idk how to fix this in a decent way. And when I click to try to solve it, a new tab called "stddef.h" appears and leads me to this line

```
#if !(defined (__GNUG__) && defined (size_t))
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
```

Sorry to bother with some tiny thing like this, but if someone could help me, I would be graceful.

I've tried to look for solutions on web, but everything sounds like greek to me.

Comment: Is `#include <stdio.h>` the only line in your source file? Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. What all did you install and configure? Do you have mixed include files for different target systems?

Comment: Judging by the flood of questions about strange linker errors from VSC, it seems super-unfriendly to beginners.

Comment: @Bodo I did only install the extensions of C/C++ from Microsoft and the Code Runner extension, and I' dont get the "mixed include files for different target systems" part. Tried to add more information to be more clear.

Comment: @Lundin, I find VSC unfriendly even to experienced developers (to me, anyway).  I'm sure I could eventually get over the learning curve, but there are alternatives available that I find much easier to use out of the box.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah... one of the main purposes of an IDE is to take care of all linker details for you, so that you don't have to write manual make files like back in the days. Writing a manual JSON instead doesn't exactly seem like an improvement.

Comment: @liljonn This is difficult to analyze without knowing what exactly you installed and did and what instructions you may have followed. The error message complains about some `typedef` in a standard include file `stddef.h`. If the name is redefined as a different type, this can mean that there is a mismatch between include files or that files were incuded with different preprocessor symbols defined. (Some type name might get defined as `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long` depending on the processor of the target system.)

Comment: @Bodo yeah, might be something like this. The `stddef.h` file is from GCC, so its a compiler error maybe. It doesn't cause trouble in the execution though, it's just a visual message. Thanks anyway

Comment: @liljonn It is probably an error in your configuration or your compiler options. I don't agree that it's just a visual message. In more complicated programs or in other situations you might get problems if different parts of your program or your main program and a library don't agree about the size of a type.

Comment: @Bodo you're right. I'm going to drop VS code for some time and use CodeBlocks instead. I'll try to reinstall all the programs and compiller later to see if it get solved.